# Unit test fails

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy, spock

I am new in Grails, I want to write unit tests for services using Spock. However I have the following issue.

```
  import grails.transaction.Transactional

    @Transactional
    class BService {

        boolean createB(){
            return true
        }
    ...
    }
```

For this class I wrote the following test:

```
class BServiceTest extends Specification {

    def "test createB"(){
        given:
        def service = new BService()

        when:
        def boolean temp
        temp = service.createB()

        then:
        temp == true
    }
}
```

The error I am getting when I run this test is the following:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No transactionManager was specified. Using @Transactional or @Rollback requires a valid configured transaction manager. If you are running in a unit test ensure the test has been properly configured and that you run the test suite not an individual test method.

and it shows in GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:60
```

I would really appreciatie if anyone can give me a hint.

Comment: Is that all? No other tests, no transactions in project?

Comment: the class Bservice includes more methods, but I did not enclosed them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you ataylor for your reply. However I did a mistake, so I am now ansewring my own question.

First of all, the name conversion is wrong. When I create a service in grails there is automatically set a unit-test for this, so in that case I would have:

```
@TestFor(BService)
class BServiceSpec extends Specification {

    def setup() {
        User u = new User(1)
        u.save()
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }

    def "test something"(){
    }
}
```

In this case when I write a unit test, it runs. 
The test that I had before was a functional test where I could not pass objects from the domain, so I had an error of the transactional manager.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `@TestFor(BService)` annotation to your unit test and use the instance of the service that it automatically provides.  See http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/testing.html for more information on testing.